# JavaScript gets rid of trailing slash in <img /> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JS code:

```
validateConfigName.html('<img src="/rta/images/check-24.png" />');
```

But when it executes in Firefox I see this as the generated code:

```
<img src="/rta/images/check-24.png">
```

Why?

Comment: @Thilo - It doesn't...but if I'm hiring a programmer, I'm after the one that *does* ask why.  I wish more people actually cared *why* something is like it is.

Comment: @Thilo - Nick is right, it doesn't. Just interested in why I was seeing the discrepancy. I already know that it's not a big deal, but was wondering if anyone with some deeper insight could definitively answer the question. What is SO good for if you can't ask the simple question of why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTML the `<img>` tag is supposed to be `<img>`, in XHTML it'll be `<img />`...so depending on what DOCTYPE your page is using, this will vary.

[From the HTML 4.0 Spec for `<img>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.2):

> Start tag: **required**, End tag: **forbidden**

[In XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) elements must be closed:

> Well-formedness is a new concept introduced by [XML]. Essentially this means that all elements must either **have closing tags** or be written in a special form (as described below), and that all the elements must nest properly.

Comment: My doctype looks like:`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: @manyxcxi - How are you viewing the code, firebug, view selection source, other?

Comment: I'm viewing using the Web Developer Toolbar FF add on. I guess I never really stopped to think about it but it makes sense that I'm not viewing exactly what the code was when I view generated code.

Comment: His DOCTYPE doesn't matter. He's not serving the page as XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Generated code, as in, like Firebug or something? Firebug operates on the DOM and not actual source code which means that it may not look exactly the same as the code you entered. It shouldn't really make a difference, though.

Comment: Using the Web Developer Toolbar add-on in Firefox I did View Generated Source.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the same thing as Firebug. It's just because it's regenerating your source instead of looking at the actual code. Nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not serving XHTML, even if your DOCTYPE is an XHTML doctype. An XHTML document isn't treated as XHTML unless you either serve it as `application/xhtml+xml`, `application/xml`, or `text/xml` using the `Content-Type` HTTP header.

Comment: Should I set this at an apache/.htaccess level or through PHP?

Answer (score 0):

It's the way, the browser renders your html code according to the doctype used.

Nothing to worry about though..