# Wordpress is removing img closing tags

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress is removing my image closing tag.

My HTML is:
/img.jpg" width="20" height="20" />

In Wordpress output looks like this:
/img.jpg" width="20" height="20" >

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you displaying the image? Are you  using `the_post_thumbnail();` or are you using something like `<img src="http://imgsrc alt="" />` or are you using it withing a template file?

Comment: Hi, Juan. This is not a dynamic created tag, it's in my core code.
<img src="http://imgsrc" alt="" />. But even with the_post_thumbnail(), <IMG shows up without the end tag.

Comment: How exactly are you inspecting the generated HTML to make your observation?

Answer (score 1):

DOM inspectors like Firebug etc. generate their own representation of the actual source code, it's possible that the closing `/` is present, but not rendered, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527597/1981996

Comment: Hi Diggy. Thanks for your help. I will read these article tomorrow morning and let you know.